# What is this audio-related component?

Tags: identification, components, speakers

This component looks like a speaker and attracts iron towards its center.

[image: front side]

[image: backside]

The numbers here lead me nowhere; the company is some audio-related company.

Shows a resistance 145 ohms.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a small speaker, probably from headphones.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at more detail (see red box): -

[image]

The red box has back-to-back diodes across the terminals and this likely means that it is a speaker from a set of headphones where the diodes shown will limit the loudness and prevent [acoustic shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_shock) on the user.

Telephone earpieces quite often used the same technique to avoid [acoustic shock](http://www.hse.gov.uk/noise/acoustic.htm).

Comment: this adds to my doubt wont one the diode short the power supply

Comment: The signal levels at the speaker are AC and require a peak-to-peak value designed to be nominally 1 volt to produce full volume. The diodes won't interfere with this voltage unless it starts to approach maybe 1.2 volts peak-to-peak.

Comment: The diodes are not "back-to-back" (which would be in series) but **anti-parallel**. The max. voltage across them would not be 1.2V but 0.6V (assuming Si diodes).

Comment: @Curd [two sets of back to back diodes](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Diode-protection-circuit-two-sets-of-back-to-back-diodes_fig5_3111639). Maybe the definition "back-to-back" has dual meaning? And, anti-parallel (or what I call back-to-back) diodes will not unduly hamper an AC voltage of 1.2 volt p-p or 0.6 volts peak. I did say "peak-to-peak above.

Comment: @Andy aka: The link is just another example of someone using the term "back-to-back" wrong. At best it would be "back-to-front", but still missleading because they are actually connected in parallel (but reversed, i.e. anti-parallel).

Answer (score 1):

It probably is a loudspeaker. Try wiring it up to an amplifier.

Comment: what is an LS(full form)

Comment: Loudspeaker!!!!

Answer (score -2):

It is most certainly **NOT** a speaker but a [**carbon microphone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_microphone) (formerly) commonly used in telephones.

The two anti-parallel diodes are there to limit any voltage across the microphone to ca. 0.6V which is enough for the generated audio signal. A much higher voltage would cause the microphone to heat up and possibly get destroyed. Maybe it was connected in a way that during certain conditions a higher voltage could be present (e.g.when the bell was rung).

You can easily verify that it is not a speaker by connecting/disconnecting a voltage source (e.g. a 1.5V battery; ideally in series with a resitor for protection). If you don't hear any clicks it is definitely not a speaker.

Hearing a rustling sound (caused by the carbon granules) when shaking the device is a strong evidence that it is a carbon microphone.

BTW: I would not overrate it beeing magentic because it could be made of iron sheet and have been laying a while next to magnet (e.g. a speaker) magentizing it.

Comment: Would the downvoter be so kind to explain the downvote?

Comment: I certainly didn't down vote but the clue might be in the opening line of the question. Read it carefully then ask yourself what role might such an addition have in a carbon microphone.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but that thing is clearly a speaker.  I've got one that looks just like it (minus the diodes) here.

Comment: @Andy aka: do you mean the "iron attraction"? I added my opinion about it at the end of my answer.

Comment: @JRE: that might be because the mass produced casing or parts of it may be used in a speaker as well as in a microphone. They have quite the same form factor in old telephones.

Comment: Please note that in addition to my assumption of it beein a carbon microphone I included in my answer an easy way to find out whether it is a speaker or not and whether it is a carbon microphone or not.

Comment: I am quit sure that it was never near or inside any electronics as i found it in a electronics component kit and they didnt even name hence the question and thus i am sure it was never near a magnet

Comment: Ok, so maybe it is a speaker. Still: What about the tests I mentioned in my answer? Do you hear clicks when connecting to a low voltage source plus resistor? Do you hear rustling sound when shaking? It would be nice if you gave some feedback if someone gives you hints to answer your question.